# The form is always invalid when I erase previously saved date with angular-datepicker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, datetime

This problem is pretty hard to explain, but I'll try.

1) I fill the form and set a value in datetime field via angular-datepicker.

2) Press submit button. Form passes validation, everything is ok, the form was submitted and saved on server.

3) I want to edit previously completed form. I open form again and see previously saved results. If I erase the value from datetime field I can't submit the form any more. When I press submit button, nothing happens, no alerts, or errors. I can only see while debugging that `operationsClientForm.$valid` is `false`.

**Important info:**

1) If I just change the value of datetime, but will not erase it, everything will be ok. Issue happens only when I erase the value.

2) If I didn't fill the datetime field first time the form will be submitted. Issue happens only when I fill datetime filed first time and then erase it, while editing.

3) It is definitely client-side error.

**Code samples:**

```
<md-input-container class="md-block defaultInput deskInput">
     <input type="text" date-time ng-model="client.date_of_birth" auto-close='true' timezone="UTC" format="DD.MM.YYYY" min-view="date" template='views\controls\datepicker.tpl.html' pattern="^(\d{2}).\d{2}.(\d{4})$">
</md-input-container>

$scope.saveClick = function (operationsClientForm) {
        if (operationsClientForm.$valid) {
              //submitting
        }
}

<md-button class="md-raised rightAlign operationButton" ng-click="saveClick(operationsClientForm)" type="submit">
    <translate>Save</translate>
</md-button>
```

Answer (score 2):

So I found the probably reason of problem. When we erase a value from datetime field, the value inside model becomes `undefined` instead of `""`. It causes parse error inside angular form validators. The obvious (and dumb at the same time) idea is to replace `undefined` by `""` in the model and then force angular validators again.

This is how it looks like:

```
<md-input-container class="md-block defaultInput deskInput">
    <input ng-blur="onDateTimeBlur($event)" type="text" date-time ng-model="client.date_of_birth" auto-close='true' timezone="UTC" format="DD.MM.YYYY" min-view="date" template='views\controls\datepicker.tpl.html' pattern="^(\d{2}).\d{2}.(\d{4})$">
</md-input-container>

    $scope.onDateTimeBlur = function (event) {
        if (event.currentTarget) {
            var modelReference = event.currentTarget.attributes["ng-model"].value;
            if (event.currentTarget.value == "") {
                this.value = "";
                this.setDeepValue(modelReference, "");
            }
        }
    };

    $scope.reValidateParseErrors = function (form) {
        var initialErrorsCount = 0;
        if (form.$error.parse) {
            initialErrorsCount = form.$error.parse.length; //to prevent infinite loop
            while (form.$error.parse) {
                form.$error.parse[0].$validate();
                if (form.$error.parse && form.$error.parse.length == initialErrorsCount) {
                    break; //break the loop if real parse errors exist
                }
            }
        }
    };

$scope.saveClick = function (operationsClientForm) {
    this.reValidateParseErrors(operationsClientForm);
    if (operationsClientForm.$valid) {
          //submitting
    }
}
```

Anyway, the qustion is still open, because my solution looks like I'm trying to overwhelm the Angular.